# Put two block inside a div using xml

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, custom-options, xml, wishlist

I did now know the xml and its layout rendering. I want to change the positions of the blocks in the wishlist xml.

Here is the file `wishlist_index_index`. And here is the  block

```
 <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info" name="customer.wishlist.item.name" template="item/column/name.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
 <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Comment" name="customer.wishlist.item.comment" template="item/column/comment.phtml" cacheable="false">
 <arguments>
   <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product Details and Comment</argument>
 </arguments>
 </block>
```

These are two different blocks now i want to wrap them inside a div ? when they appear in the html side. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a **container** and place both blocks in it

```
<container name="custom.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="your_class" after="-">

        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info" name="customer.wishlist.item.name" template="item/column/name.phtml" cacheable="false"/>

                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Comment" name="customer.wishlist.item.comment" template="item/column/comment.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product Details and Comment</argument>
                    </arguments>

        </block>
</container>
```

or move these block in the required container, like

```
 <move element="customer.wishlist.item.name" destination="custom.container" before="-" />
 <move element="customer.wishlist.item.comment" destination="custom.container" after="customer.wishlist.item.name" />
```

Comment: I have wrap it in container but the name and comment box is now not showing.

Comment: these are child blocks, you can start a <div> in  item/column/name.phtml and close in item/column/comment.phtml.
This in not a good approach but it will work

Comment: is it a good approach or it is a hack? i mean if i really want to make a block of div there?

Comment: it is a hack, but will not create any issue

Comment: It is also a standard one. No issues will be created by doing this. best practice by xml files

Answer (score 0):

```
<block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info" name="customer.wishlist.item.name" template="item/column/name.phtml" cacheable="false">

                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Comment" name="customer.wishlist.item.comment" as="customer.wishlist.item.comment" template="item/column/comment.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product Details and Comment</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
</block> <!-- close your block here -->
```

Now in your `name.phtml` start your `div` tag with your content and at the end of content of `item.phtml` just call

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('customer.wishlist.item.comment'); ?>
```

and end your `div` tag after this line

Comment: these are parallel blocks not one block inside another block.